# CSV filter in logstash throwing "_csvparsefailure" error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I asked another question eairler which I think might be related to this question:
[JSON parser in logstash ignoring data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713336/json-parser-in-logstash-ignoring-data)
The reason I think it's related is because in the previous question kibana wasn't displaying results from the JSON parser which have the "PROGRAM" field as "mfd_status". Now I'm changing the way I do things, removed the JSON parser just in case it might be interfering with stuff, but I still don't have any logs with "mfd_status" in them showing up.

```
csv 
{
    columns => ["unixTime", "unixTime2", "FACILITY_NUM", "LEVEL_NUM", "PROGRAM", "PID", "MSG_FULL"]
    source => "message"
    separator => "  "
}
```

In my filter from the previous question I used two grok filters, now I've replaced them with a csv filter. I also have two date and a fingerprint filter but they're irrelevant for this question, I think.

Example log messages:

> "1452564798.76\t1452496397.00\t1\t4\tkernel\t\t[ 6252.000246] sonar: sonar_write(): waiting..."

OUTPUT:

```
        "unixTime" => "1452564798.76",
       "unixTime2" => "1452496397.00",
    "FACILITY_NUM" => "1",
       "LEVEL_NUM" => "4",
         "PROGRAM" => "kernel",
             "PID" => nil,
        "MSG_FULL" => "[ 6252.000246] sonar: sonar_write(): waiting...",
       "TIMESTAMP" => "2016-01-12T02:13:18.760Z",
"TIMESTAMP_second" => "2016-01-11T07:13:17.000Z"
```

> "1452564804.57\t1452496403.00\t1\t7\tmfd_status\t\t00800F08CFB0\textra\t{\"date\":1452543203,\"host\":\"ABCD1234\",\"inet\":[\"169.254.42.207/16\",\"10.8.207.176/32\",\"172.22.42.207/16\"],\"fb0\":[\"U:1280x800p-60\",32]}"

OUTPUT:

```
       "tags" => [
    [0] "_csvparsefailure"
```

After it says kernel/mfd_status in the logs, there shouldn't be any more deliminators and it should all go under the MSG_FULL field.

So, to summarize, why does one of my log messages parse correctly and the other one not? Also, even if it doesn't parse correctly it should still send it to elasticsearch just with empty fields, I think, why doesn't it do that either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost good, you need to override two more parameters in your CSV filter and both lines will be parsed correctly.

The first is `skip_empty_columns => true` because you have one empty field in your second log line and you need to ignore it.

The second is `quote_char=> "'"` (or anything else than the double quote `"`) since your JSON contain double quotes.

```
csv {
    columns => ["unixTime", "unixTime2", "FACILITY_NUM", "LEVEL_NUM", "PROGRAM", "PID", "MSG_FULL"]
    source => "message"
    separator => "  "
    skip_empty_columns => true
    quote_char => "'"
}
```

Using this, your first log line parses as:

```
{
         "message" => "1452564798.76\\t1452496397.00\\t1\\t4\\tkernel\\t\\t[ 6252.000246] sonar: sonar_write(): waiting...",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-01-12T04:21:34.051Z",
            "host" => "iMac.local",
        "unixTime" => "1452564798.76",
       "unixTime2" => "1452496397.00",
    "FACILITY_NUM" => "1",
       "LEVEL_NUM" => "4",
         "PROGRAM" => "kernel",
        "MSG_FULL" => "[ 6252.000246] sonar: sonar_write(): waiting..."
}
```

And the second log lines parses as:

```
{
         "message" => "1452564804.57\\t1452496403.00\\t1\\t7\\tmfd_status\\t\\t00800F08CFB0\\textra\\t{\\\"date\\\":1452543203,\\\"host\\\":\\\"ABCD1234\\\",\\\"inet\\\":[\\\"169.254.42.207/16\\\",\\\"10.8.207.176/32\\\",\\\"172.22.42.207/16\\\"],\\\"fb0\\\":[\\\"U:1280x800p-60\\\",32]}",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2016-01-12T04:21:07.974Z",
            "host" => "iMac.local",
        "unixTime" => "1452564804.57",
       "unixTime2" => "1452496403.00",
    "FACILITY_NUM" => "1",
       "LEVEL_NUM" => "7",
         "PROGRAM" => "mfd_status",
        "MSG_FULL" => "00800F08CFB0",
         "column8" => "extra",
         "column9" => "{\\\"date\\\":1452543203,\\\"host\\\":\\\"ABCD1234\\\",\\\"inet\\\":[\\\"169.254.42.207/16\\\",\\\"10.8.207.176/32\\\",\\\"172.22.42.207/16\\\"],\\\"fb0\\\":[\\\"U:1280x800p-60\\\",32]}"
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks :D